# Update column IF exists else insert

Tags: mysql

I know about `ON DUPLICATE USE KEY` clauses. But I can not use it since I want to `update` and `insert` on non-unique column.

I have `table1` and `table2`. I want to create a trigger on `table1`.

Pseudocode:

```
IF id_code for corresponding id_name from table1 is present in table2
then update record in table 2
else record in table2.
```

For Ex.

```
table1 has column1 id_code, column2 id_name
table2 has column1 id_code, column2 status

IF id_code for corresponding id_name from table1 is present in table2
UPDATE status column in table2.
ELSE insert id-code in table2
```

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Comment: *"I want to create trigger"* -- take a look at some examples: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Create a trigger, then use insert ... on duplicate key update ... within it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would probably be to use a conditional statement, since as you said you are checking for a non unique value and thus cannot use ON DUPLICATE KEY:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id_code FROM table2 WHERE id_code = 'code from table1') THEN
    UPDATE table2 SET status = 'new status' WHERE id_code = 'code from table1';
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table2 (id_code, status) VALUES ('code from table1', 'new status');
END IF;
```

The only caveat here is that control structures are only valid in stored procedures, so you will need to put this in a stored procedure or a trigger.

Comment: I want to create trigger and not SP,
can I use above code in trigger ??

Comment: Yes you can also use it in a trigger.